# Convert Animated SVG to Video

Tags: android, ios, .net, video, svg

I have this interesting problem. I need to convert animated SVG or just plain SVG to a video format either on the client side (iOS/Android) or on the server side (.NET).
There does not seems to be a way to accomplish it.
My initial approach was to animate SVG using Core Animation (on iOS) and convert that to a video, but a similar solution does not exist in the Android world.

My next approach was to use FFMPEG, but that too fell short. then I shifted my focus to .NET, but that too, nothing came out of it.

I'm looking for some general direction. Can it be done?
The idea is to take multiple SVGs and convert them to a video file along with some audio.
Thanks in advance!